# as3 Error type was not found but already import

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problems when I want to compile my code. There are errors

```
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SliderEvent
```

But I have already import it.

```
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
```

When I right click and `GotoDeclaration`. I notice that those files is not include

in my project. What should I do? I think fl library should already include into my project.

Comment: Your `fl` library might be included but maybe the `SliderEvent` is not in there. Check your folder if it exists (It sounds like it doesn't). You might have an older version of Flash? What version are you using?

Comment: SliderEvent definition is located at C:\Program files(x86)\FlashDevelop\Library\AS3\frameworks\FlashIDE\events\SliderEvent.as and I have installed Flash Player 11 already.

Comment: But it should be in a folder like 'fl/events/'

Comment: It's not, or I set wrong path.

Comment: You likely did. In my FlashDevelop installation, it's at ...\frameworks\FlashIDE\fl\events\SliderEvent.as

Comment: Could you tell me your Path in Tool > Program Setting > AS3Context > Installed Flex SDKs? There are members and location which I'm sure I put it wrong.